# How to add a view at bottom of tabcontroller in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image: Like Below Image]

I need to add a view at bottom of Tab Controller like:

**For example:** A view in activity which draws over the fragments in tabs. Similar view in flutter.

I tried adding container or column or row none of them worked. Just showed a blank space.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return MaterialApp(
    home: Container(
  child: DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Project Name"),
          bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
            Tab(
              text: "Status",
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Checking",
            )
          ]),
        ),
        body: new Container(
          child: TabBarView(children: [TabDetail1(), TabDetail2()]),
        ),
      )),
));


TabDetails1

       class TabDetails1extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return TabDetails1State();
  }
}

    class TabDetails1State extends State<TabDetails1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            child: Text(
              "Connected To:",
            ),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10, 0, 0),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: Text(
              "Equipment Id :",
            ),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10, 0, 0),
          ),
          new Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Text("Status"),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  width: 50,
                ),
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text(
                          "MWM Status",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    ),
                    new Flexible(
                      child: new Container(
                        child: new Image.asset('assets/images/and.jpg'),
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                      ),
                      flex: 0,
                    ),
                    new Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text(
                          "Not Connected",
                          maxLines: 1,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    )
                  ],
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                ),
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text(
                          "GPRS Status",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: new Container(
                        child: new Image.asset('assets/images/and.jpg'),
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                      flex: 0,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text("GPS Connected"),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    ),
                  ],
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                ),
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text(
                          "SIM Status",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: new Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                        child: new Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/and.jpg',
                          width: 50,
                          height: 50,
                        ),
                      ),
                      fit: FlexFit.tight,
                      flex: 0,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text(
                          "Not Connected",
                          maxLines: 1,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    )
                  ],
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                ),
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text(
                          "RDMS Status",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: new Container(
                        child: new Image.asset('assets/images/and.jpg'),
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                      flex: 0,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text("Not Connected"),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    ),
                  ],
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So this contains the TabDetails1 where it renders this container.

Comment: Try wrapping the Container for the body in a column then add the extra button underneath it

Comment: Not working showing black space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use 'SizedBox'
You can see the error as below:

```
I/flutter (20325): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (20325): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter (20325): Horizontal viewport was given unbounded width.
```

It comes from the code as below:

```
@override
void performResize() {
  assert(() {
    if (!constraints.hasBoundedHeight || !constraints.hasBoundedWidth) {
      switch (axis) {
        case Axis.vertical:
          if (!constraints.hasBoundedHeight) {
            throw FlutterError(
              'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.\n'
```

Because the `TabBarView` does not have `hasBoundedHeight`.
So, We have to use the `SizedBox` or `AspectRatio` what have the limited height with widget. I set 500 as the height of `SizedBox`.

This is the full code as following:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: SizedBox(
              height: 500,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child:TabBarView(
                  children: [
                    TabDetail1(),
                    TabDetail1(),
                    TabDetail1(),
                  ]
                )),
                Container(child: Text("hello", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0)))
              ]
            )
          ),
      )
    );
}
```

```
  Widget TabDetail1(){
    return new Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            child: Text(
              "Connected To:",
            ),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10, 0, 0),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: Text(
              "Equipment Id :",
            ),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10, 0, 0),
          ),
          new Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Text("Status"),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  width: 50,
                ),
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text(
                          "MWM Status",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    ),
                    new Flexible(
                      child: new Container(
                        child: new Image.asset('assets/images/and.jpg'),
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                      ),
                      flex: 0,
                    ),
                    new Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text(
                          "Not Connected",
                          maxLines: 1,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    )
                  ],
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                ),
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text(
                          "GPRS Status",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: new Container(
                        child: new Image.asset('assets/images/and.jpg'),
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                      flex: 0,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text("GPS Connected"),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    ),
                  ],
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                ),
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text(
                          "SIM Status",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: new Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                        child: new Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/and.jpg',
                          width: 50,
                          height: 50,
                        ),
                      ),
                      fit: FlexFit.tight,
                      flex: 0,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text(
                          "Not Connected",
                          maxLines: 1,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    )
                  ],
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                ),
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text(
                          "RDMS Status",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: new Container(
                        child: new Image.asset('assets/images/and.jpg'),
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                      flex: 0,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text("Not Connected"),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      ),
                      flex: 1,
                    ),
                  ],
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not deal with the answer!

Comment: Not working,  Container(child: Text("hello", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0)) . How does the container came there?

Comment: @DayaNithi What does `TabDetail1` contains?

Comment: It contains a container with views in it. eg: A layout design.

Comment: I have edited the question please check and update.

Comment: @DayaNithi  I just implemented with your code. I think it works. Please compare the code with yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194850/discussion-between-daya-nithi-and-yaho-cho).